# How to - Looping midi playback using MusicSequence and MusicPlayer

Tags: ios, loops, playback, midi

I've finally managed to load and playback midifiles using the MusicSequence and MusicPlayer API as well as AUSampler for delivering the sound samples.

Is there any (simple) way of looping the actual midi sequence in the MusicPlayer or do I have to make my own timing calculations and restart the player from the beginning "manually"? I'm afraid of losing exact miditiming if the latter is true, especially because I'm using very short 1-bar loops, so I had to restart the playback very often.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: OK - figured it out by myself, that you can find this information in the apple documentation. For all, who look here:`MusicTrack t1;  
    MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(s, 1, &t1);  
    
    MusicTrackLoopInfo loopInfo = { 4, 0 };  
    OSStatus result = MusicTrackSetProperty(t1,
                                             kSequenceTrackProperty_LoopInfo, &loopInfo,
                                             sizeof(MusicTrackLoopInfo));`